# networkInfo.isConnected() method return true even there is no internet?

Tags: android, networkinfo

[image: my app]

i develop this app , in the main activity i check the internet connection as the following :

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        LoaderManager loaderManager = getSupportLoaderManager();
        loaderManager.initLoader(1, null, this);

    }
```

when i go to `HOURLY` activity i check the internet in the same way like above on the `onCreate()` method.

my question when i open the main activity i disconnect the internet and go to `HOURLY` activity to handle "no internet exception" but networkInfo.isConnected() in  `HOURLY` activity return `true` why the internet still connect???

Comment: Disconnect your mobile signal as well?